# Can a function whose points are all local minima can be non-constant?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ attains its local minima on every point of its domain. Is $f$ necessarily a constant function?

Definition of $x$ being a local minimum of $f$: for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\epsilon_x > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $y \in (x - \epsilon_x, x + \epsilon_x)$.

Note: $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. I believe $f$ to be either a constant function or a function with an extreme behavior.

Comment: +1 Very intriguing question that I have no idea how to approach, especially since $f$ is not assumed to be continuous.  It seems to me that the first step would be to (somehow) prove that $f$ must be continuous, but I'm unsure whether this conjecture is even true.

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise is a counterexample. – Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402071/42969.

Comment: I was fooled too (not sure if that will help you to feel better !) @user2661923

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f=2\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}+\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, 0]\cup [1,\infty)}$

has all points that are local minimal.

If $f$ is continuos, then it is clear the only function is a constant:

We fix $f(a)\in \mathbb{R}$ and we define the set $A:=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(a)\leq f(x)\}$

Clearly $A$ is not empty, $a\in A$. Moreover it is closed because $[f(a),\infty)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}([f(a),\infty))=A$ is closed.
By your assumption, if $x_0\in A$, $x_0$ is a local minimal of $f$, I.e. $f(a)=f_(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for each $x\in U$, where $U$ is some neighbourhood of $x_0$. This means $U\subseteq A$ and so $A$ is a closed and open in the connected set $\mathbb{R}$. This permit us to say

$\mathbb{R}=A=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(a)\leq f(x)\}$ for each choice of $a$.

But then if you consider a generic $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, you get

$f(a)\leq f(x_0)$

Conversely

$a\in \mathbb{R}=\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x_0)\leq f(x)\}$

and so

$f(x_0)\leq f(a)$

Thus $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: In other words ,piecewise constants functions where the lower part has closed boundaries are the answer.

Comment: @nicomezi Are you from the future?

Comment: @nicomezi They don't even have to be piecewise constant. Consider the negative indicator function of the middle-thirds Cantor set; it has uncountably many discontinuities.

Comment: I agree with you, it was just a poor choice of words on my part. I surely did not mean it included all the functions satisfying the requirements. Nice example though. @ChrisCulter