# Functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with a local minimum at every point

Tags: real-analysis

We say that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has a local minimum at every point, if for any point $x_0$ we can find an open interval containing $x_0$ such that $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$ for every point in the interval. Suppose $f$ is **any** function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying this condition (so, in particular, it is not necessarily continuous).

It does not follow that $f$ is constant. For example, take $f$ to be 0 on the integers and 1 elsewhere.

So the question is prove that $f$ is constant except at (at most) countably many points, or find a counter-example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402176/42969

Comment: @MartinR You are correct. This is essentially a duplicate. I will delete it. Many thanks. I searched on local minimum before posting, but failed to search on local maximum! Grrr. The systems seems to be against deleting answered questions, so I will modify it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the rules any more. I read @MartinR's comment and realised he was correct, the question was a duplicate. I tried to close it, but the system told me not to close it, because it already had an answer. It suggested modifying the question. Whilst I am doing that, someone else closed it and the system doesn't even tell me who. There is much good stuff on MSE but I find its closure rules increasingly irritating.

Comment: I closed your question because you confirmed that it is a duplicate. (You could have closed it yourself as a duplicate, you just cannot *delete* it if there are two or more answers.) I can reopen the question now that you modified it. Just note that modifying question after receiving answers may invalidate existing answers, so often it is better to ask a new question.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, thanks. Yes, I see the distinction between closing and deleting. I should have closed it! I also take the point about better not to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Your example where $f$ is $0$ on the integers and $1$ elsewhere does not use the fact that the integers are a countable set, only that they are a closed set (i.e. that its complement is open)

Comment: Many thanks. Stupid of me - I thought briefly about the Cantor set, but missed the point.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(x) = -\lfloor x \rfloor$.  ([see definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) .)
This function has a local minimum at every point, but $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = -\infty$.

So the function is not "constant" except at countably many points.  It is "locally constant" except at countably many points.

---

As maritsm remarked, a "closed set" will do, instead of the countable set of the OP.  Let $C$ be the Cantor set, and let $f(x) = 0$ on $C$ and, for each interval of the  complement $\mathbb R \setminus C$, let $f(x)$ be a negative constant; possibly different constants for each such interval.
Now we could have $\inf f = -\infty$ and $f$ is locally constant except on the **uncountable** set $C$.