# Prove a function is constant over an interval

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function of $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies $$\forall \ x_0 \in \mathbb{R},\ \exists \  \delta > 0,\ f(x_0) \geq f(x),\ \forall x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta).$$

Prove that there exists a nondegenerate interval $I$, $f$ is constant over $I$.

There are no conditions on the continuity of $f$, so I don't know where to start. I tried the principle of nested intervals but failed.

Any kind of help is appreciated and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402071/if-every-point-is-a-local-maximum-is-it-a-step-function    may be useful

Comment: @BotnakovN. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402071/if-every-point-is-a-local-maximum-is-it-a-step-function/1402176#1402176) linked in comments, we know $f$ attains at most countably many values.  Thus by formulation BCT3 of the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), we know there exists some $y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is not [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set). That is there exists a closed interval $I$, such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is dense on $I$.

Thus the minimum value of $f$ on $I$ is $y$, as no smaller value can be a local maximum.  Pick $x\in {\rm int}(I)$ with $f(x)=y$.  We have some closed interval $x\in J\subseteq I$ with the maximum value of $f$ on $J$ being $y$.

We already know the minimum value of $f$ on $J$ is $y$.  Thus $f$ is constant on $J$.