# Question related to when the intersection of a nested interval is a singleton - When can the end points equal the singular element in the intersection

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I am given a sequence of intervals $I_n:=[a_n,b_n]$ with $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ for all $n\geq0$.

Moreover, I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n-a_n=0$.

These two facts allow us to conclude that $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=0}I_n$ is a singleton. Let $p$ be the name of the sole element in $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=0}I_n$.

Under what circumstances can I guarantee that there exists no $n$ such that $a_n=p$ or $b_n=p$?

My thought is that if I can show  $\forall i \in \mathbb N: a_i \lt a_{i+1}$ **and** $b_i \gt b_{i+1}$, then I can guarantee the above statement.

However, if we only knew that $\forall i \in \mathbb N: a_i \leq a_{i+1}$ **or** $b_i \geq b_{i+1}$, then no such guarantee can be made.

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. If, for example there is an $N$ such that $a_N=p$ then it must be the case that $a_n=p$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales great. Thank you for confirming my thoughts. Cheers!

Comment: Note that $a_n$ increases while $b_n$ decreases; they both converge to $p.$ You want them to not be eventually constant. Therefore, a necessary and sufficient condition for they never to equal $p$ is that there cannot exists an $N$ such that the relation$n \geq N$ implies either $a_n = p$ or $b_n = p.$